# Is it possible to get an analytic expression of the capacitance for this geometry?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance

Here is the geometry I'm talking about:

[image]

Assume the red rectangle is at some constant potential V, like 10 Volts, and the blue is at ground. We can assume that the rectangles extend infinitely (to the left and right, respectively) if that makes things easier, but we can't make them shorter, because that would start to change the problem at hand.

What I'm ultimately doing is this: solving for the potential everywhere given these boundary conditions, using that to get the E field everywhere, and then integrating $|E|^2$ over all space (outside the rectangles) to get the total field energy. Setting this equal to $CV^2$ will let me solve for the capacitance.

This is more complicated than just a parallel plate capacitor, because I want to look at small dimensions, where the fringing fields start becoming the majority of the field, which changes the capacitance.

What I'm looking for is an analytic *expression*, even if the real world value of that expression must be computed, for the capacitance. For example, many of the boundary condition problems in Jackson (chapters 2 and 3) have analytic solutions, but they are pretty hefty summations. I'm okay with that, because it will still be faster than using Finite Element methods.

I've briefly investigated how I'd do it, but I get stumped because it seems like the potential *isn't* separable. For example, if you take a cross section of the potential perpendicular to the interface, it looks like this:

[image]

...but only for the width of the other dimension (the one that's not in the cross section). So that makes it seem like it's not separable. Even if it was, I'm not sure how I'd solve the 2D potential above, because it has multiple corners and such.

Is there some analytic series solution to this?

Comment: I don't think there is an analytical solution, but for an infinite wire of any shape the capacitance would have to be infinite. Imagine that you connect a voltage source between the two conductors and current starts flowing. Both conductors form an infinite dipole antenna, so the current pulse will just keep flowing down either, but it can never charge the entire conductor to a constant voltage. Other than that I suspect the problem can still be simplified with image charges.

Comment: @CuriousOne, good point about the infinite capacitance. The current explanation confuses me, but could I just think of it this way? If you had an infinitely long wire *already* at some voltage, the E field integral over all space would be infinite, meaning C is also infinite? So therefore, two infinitely long ones would also have infinite E field over all space? I guess the smart thing to do would be to look at some capacitance per unit area or volume, I guess.

Comment: @CuriousOne regarding the image charges, I briefly thought about it, but kind of stalled because IME with method of images problem, you usually turn a charged/potential object and semi-infinite plane *into* a problem with this type of symmetry (where the thing that you turn it into is way simpler). But I would be very interested if you have any ideas of how it could be done.

Comment: Yes, for a given voltage the charge density has to be finite and this leads to an infinite energy. I just like thinking about long wires dynamically since the speed of light is finite, which leads to an infinite time to charge.

Comment: The image charge method gets rid of one conductor. I wonder if one could use it to find an iterative solution?

Comment: @CuriousOne, hmmm, my only experience with the iterative MoI strategy is the problem of a charged sphere next to an infinite plane, you mean like that? But again, with that one, they go from that setup to two charged spheres, and iteratively use the solution for a point charge next to a charged sphere. I may just have to go with FEA, which I've already implemented. I just wanted to see if there were a smarter way.

Comment: There are definitely smarter ways than what I am suggesting. The other question is, how precise do you need this to be? What are you doing with the result?